# ARM socket connection with user input for IP address

Tags: sockets, assembly, network-programming, arm

I want to get user's input from the console and use the IP address for a socket connection instead of hardcoding the IP address.

From my learning on https://azeria-labs.com/tcp-bind-shell-in-assembly-arm-32-bit/, I modified the socket structure (still using a hardcoded address) as such:

```
    struct:
    .ascii "\x02\xff"
    .ascii "\x11\x5c"
    ipv4: .byte 0
    ipv4_2: .byte 0
    ipv4_3: .byte 0
    ipv4_4: .byte 0
```

I then copy the actual address to the 4 bytes for IP address

```
    adr r1,ipv4
    mov r2,#127
    strb r2, [r1]

    adr r1,ipv4_2
    mov r2,#0
    strb r2, [r1]

    adr r1,ipv4_3
    mov r2,#0
    strb r2, [r1]

    adr r1,ipv4_4
    mov r2,#1
    strb r2, [r1]
```

The connection will complete successfully. However, if I want to get an IP address input from user, such as 255.255.255.255, each single digit actually takes up one byte individually, so 255 is treated as 0x2 0x5 0x5, instead of 0xff which is the intended interpretation (one byte). The code to read input:

```
    mov r7,#3
    mov r0,#0
    adr r1,userinput
    mov r2,#20
    svc #1
```

How do I "combine" the three digits into one and then store it in a single byte?

If that is not the way, what is the correct way to do it? Is it possible to do it without the use of external libc functions?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you writing in assembler instead of e.g. C? Or not use the standard C functions and the operating system (if any)?

Comment: Use elementary mathematics. `x=a*100+b*10+c` with `a`,`b` and `c` being the single digits. Note you will also need to convert from ascii. See any of the dozens of examples for string to number conversion. That's assuming you can't use C library in which case you could just `scanf` or `atoi`/`strtol`.

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude, I was curious if it was possible to do it without relying on external libraries.

Comment: Hi @Jester, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will take a look at those topics.